# Bootstrap 3 input spinner with negative values

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, integer, asp.net-mvc-5, spinner, negative-number

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application and am wanting to add an input spinner control for my integer values in my MVC views.

I have looked on the Bootstrap 3 website and cannot find a spinner control. I am wanting the input spinner to be able to have negative numbers.

Does Bootstrap 3 have such a control and if not, where should I find one that works with negative numbers as well as positive numbers?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I have found some third party spinners, yet they do not appear to enable negative numbers. Here is an example: http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-touchspin/

Does such a control exist?

Comment: Actually that spinner allows negative numbers. You have to set `min` to some negative number. See the second example on that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By *spinner* if you mean an input field, then it is an HTML5 utility, not Bootstrap's.

```
<input type="number">
```

Above code will give you a *spinner*.

Comment: Although Bootstrap will style `input[type=number]` a bit if you add the `form-control` class to it.